# Case assignment logic

Tags: case, assignment-rules, case-object

[image: Case creation]

Where can I possibly find logic which is changing the case owner to the present user to a queue? 
will it be in trigger or some assignment rules? 
I have checked with assignment rules it doesn't have anything defined in it.
So what are the posible ways in which we can assign the case owner.

Comment: Please check Support Settings (Setup > Customize > Cases) and verify the Default Case Owner

Answer (score 0):

Go to Setup -> Support Settings check "Default Case Owner".  See below for reference.

[image]

If Default Case Owner is different then check, is there any trigger is updating Case Owner or not.

Answer (score 0):

Reassign Case using a Quick Action and Flow

Reference :- `https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/salesforcesidekick.com/2016/01/11/reassign-case-using-a-quick-action-and-flow/amp/`

I cannot write each and every step, so i am highlighting the content in short:-

You will need to create two fields,  a quick action and add it to layout, a process builder and a flow which consist:-

- create a variable to store our Queue Name, which we will pass in from our Process Builde
- create a variable to store that ID that we are looking to get.
- use a Decision to validate that we found an Id
- create a variable to house our Case Id that we are going to pass in from our Process Builder.  This allows us to make sure we are updating the correct Case.
- once Flow is completed and activated, but right now its doing nothing!  So we need to have a Process Builder trigger it.